# How can I limit a user to only see one project in Jira

Tags: jira

We are adding third party users to our Jira environment where we want them to only view a single project that we have added them to.

However due to many of our projects being set up as "open" and not "private" it enables a third party user to see all "open" projects. From what I have researched you can not change this "open" flag once a project has been created either.

So I'm hoping that there is a way to either create a group or individual level of permission that prevents a user from seeing any projects but those they are invited to/granted access to.